# Find annual MAX and MIN per employee using quarterly data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working from a database in SQL server which contains quarterly employee sales quota in USD. The table I'm retrieving my information from contains the following columns:

- SalesQuotaKey (PK, int, NOT NULL)
- Employee Key (FK, int, NOT NULL)
- DateKey (FK, int, NOT NULL)
- Calendar Year (smallint, NOT NULL)
- Calendar Quarter (tinyint, NOT NULL)
- SalesAmountQuota (money, NOT NULL)
- Date (datetime, NOT NULL)

The column containing the SalesAmountQuota shows the quarterly quota.

Sample data and expected result for one EmployeeID stated below
    Employeekey Datekey         Year   quarter  SalesAmountquota  Date

```
1   272 20101229    2010    4   28000,00    2010-12-29 00:00:00.000
11  272 20110331    2011    1   7000,00 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000
21  272 20110701    2011    3   91000,00    2011-07-01 00:00:00.000
31  272 20110929    2011    3   140000,00   2011-09-29 00:00:00.000
41  272 20111229    2011    4   70000,00    2011-12-29 00:00:00.000
54  272 20120330    2012    1   154000,00   2012-03-30 00:00:00.000
68  272 20120630    2012    2   107000,00   2012-06-30 00:00:00.000
82  272 20120928    2012    3   58000,00    2012-09-28 00:00:00.000
96  272 20121228    2012    4   263000,00   2012-12-28 00:00:00.000
113 272 20130330    2013    1   116000,00   2013-03-30 00:00:00.000
130 272 20130630    2013    2   84000,00    2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
147 272 20130929    2013    3   187000,00   2013-09-29 00:00:00.000
```

emp key MaxSalesQuota   MinSalesquota

```
 272    582000,00   28000,00
```

However, I want to create an overview which shows both the *highest ever annual* sales quotum and *lowest ever annual* sales quotum ever for each EmployeeID (only for the years where the all four quarterly quota contain a value)

I managed to find the highest and lowest ever quarterly sales quotum per employee using the below statement but I am having trouble to create a statement that retrieves the highest and lowest annual quotum per employee.
Anyone who can help me out? Your help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT A.EmployeeKey,
       MAX(A.SalesAmountQuota) as MaxQuota,
       Min(B.SalesAmountQuota) as MinQuota 
FROM FactSalesQuota A, FactSalesQuota B
WHERE A.SalesAmountQuota = B.SalesAmountQuota
GROUP BY A.EmployeeKey
ORDER BY A.EmployeeKey
```

Comment: Do come and join us in 1992 :) [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) & [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: On a different note, if you want by year, seems you just need to add the Year to your `SELECT` and `GROUP By`. Also, why are you joining the table to itself on the same column? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Larnu Indeed, joining doesn't make sense, my bad.
I don't want it by year, I only want to retrieve the highest and lowest quota ever per employee, meaning it needs to retrieve the sum of the 4 quarterly quota for the years in which the sum was the highest ever and lowest ever.

Comment: That sample data and expected results that @jarlh asked for will really help us understand here then.

Comment: @Larnu See openingpost for sampledata

Comment: @YH93 please provide your excepted output :)

Comment: @pascalsanchez Done :)

Comment: I don't understand the result you are showing. Years 2010 and 2013 are incomplete. 2011 has a sum of 582000, 2012 a sum of 308000. So why do you have 28000 in your result?

Answer (score 4):

Have a derived table where you `SUM()` annual quota for each employee, use `HAVING` clause to make sure all 4 quarters are there for each year. Then pick max and min annual quota:

```
select EmployeeKey, max(YearQuota ), min(YearQuota)
from
(
    SELECT EmployeeKey, SUM(SalesAmountQuota) as YearQuota 
    FROM FactSalesQuota
    GROUP BY EmployeeKey, CalendarYear
    HAVING count(distinct CalendarQuarter) = 4 
) dt
group by EmployeeKey
```

Comment: This one does the job!
Thanks a lot!
I Always seem to forget that I can use a specific select statement when specifying the source table.

Comment: Only thing to find out is how I can exclude the years for which not all four quarters are present in the data.

Comment: Missed that part. Stay tuned. Done!

Comment: Thanks! Almost there!. Adding the HAVING statement results in SQL giving the same values for both Min and Max.

Comment: @YH93: The query is correct. MIN can equal MAX when an employee has only one year with four quarters or when all such years have the same sum.